# If $A$ is a direct sum of matrix algebra over $C$, what are all finite dimensional simple $A$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, direct-sum, semisimple-lie-algebras

If $A$ is a direct sum of matrix algebra, what are all finite-dim simple $A$-modules?

For simple case of $2$ matrix algebras, consider $A = M_n(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_m(\mathbb{C})$. Suppose $M$ is a finite dimensional $A$-module, then it is automatically a finite dimensional $M_n(\mathbb{C}) $-module and a finite dimensional $M_m(\mathbb{C}) $-module. In particular, $M$ must be both a direct sum of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and of $\mathbb{C}^m$ (This is because, if $M$ is a $M_n(\mathbb{C})$-module, fix $ a_0 \in M$, then $\mathbb{C}^n \cong M_n(\mathbb{C})a_0$ is a simple $M_n(\mathbb{C})$-module, and we can choose $a_1 \notin M_n(\mathbb{C})a_0$ and decompose $M$ into a direct sum of $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Therefore, $$M = \bigoplus_j^N(\bigoplus_{1 \leq i \leq n} \mathbb{C}^m) = \bigoplus_j^N(\bigoplus_{1 \leq i \leq m} \mathbb{C}^n) = \bigoplus_j^N( \mathbb{C}^{m} \otimes_\mathbb{C}  \mathbb{C}^{n}) = \bigoplus_j^N( \mathbb{C}^{mn}) = \mathbb{C}^{mnN} .$$

Let $M_m(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^{m} \otimes_\mathbb{C}  \mathbb{C}^{n}$ naturally on each  component, then it is easy to see the action is transitive and that it is stable under action, making it a simple $A$-module. Thus all $M$ is a direct sum of simple $A$-module $\mathbb{C}^{m} \otimes_\mathbb{C}  \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and this classifies all simple $A$-modules. For any direct sum $A = \bigoplus_j M_{n_j}(\mathbb{C})$, the simple
$A$-module is therefore $M^{\Pi_jm_j}$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: It's not true that an $A$-module is an $M_n(\mathbb{C})$-module. The identity element of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ may not act as the identity.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment! Is there any way to change the proof and make it work? Like show that M is a direct sum of $M_m(C)$-module and $M_n(C)$-module to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me generalize the question. Suppose $A$ is the direct sum $R\oplus S$ of two rings (though I prefer the terminology/notation "direct product $R\times S$"), and let $M$ be a (right) $A$-module.

Let $e=(1_R,0)\in A$ and $f=(0,1_S)\in A$. Then $Me$ and $Mf$ are both $A$-modules, and $M = Me\oplus Mf$. $Me$ has a natural $R$-module structure, and $S$ acts on it as zero. $Mf$ has a natural $S$-module structure, and $R$ acts on it as zero.

So any $A$-module $M$ is the direct sum of an $R$-module and an $S$-module. In particular, the simple $A$-modules are just the simple $R$-modules (with $S$ acting as zero) and the simple $S$-modules (with $R$ acting as zero).

In the case $A=M_n(\mathbb{C})\oplus M_m(\mathbb{C})$, $A$ has two simple modules (up to isomorphism): the $n$-dimensional simple $M_n(\mathbb{C})$-module, with $M_m(\mathbb{C})$ acting as zero, and the $m$-dimensional simple $M_m(\mathbb{C})$-module, with $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ acting as zero.

Comment: Yes. If $R$ and $S$ are semisimple rings with decompositions $R\cong \oplus R_i$ and $S\cong  \oplus S_j$ into its simple $R$-modules (respectively $S$-modules), then $R\oplus S\cong \left(\oplus R_i \right)\oplus \left(\oplus S_j\right)$ is semisimple and hence there are no more simple modules. We do not need the notion of semisimple for this question, as your answer shows, but for studying the simple modules of the tensor product $R\otimes S$ it is very useful. For the same reason, their simple modules are $R_i\otimes S_j$, where $R_i$ is $R$-simple and $S_j$ is $S$-simple.